# VS 2010 Database Project Run Script Conditionally

Tags: visual-studio-2010, database-project

I am new to VS 2010 database projects, in the past I've used dbp projects but are not longer supported in VS 2010.

I would like to run a set of sql scripts that add test data, but would ideally like this to only run based on the project configuration.

For example, if I can have a VS "Test" configuration that would execute this set of scripts.

I am currently using the PostDeployment.sql to add other scripts to run on post deployment.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This looks similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3856553/managing-sample-data-with-vs-2010-database

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to set up variables for your project and then reference them when you do your build/deploy. For our case, we have a "DeployType" variable that can help us run certain scripts for certain environments.

In your post-deploy script, you'd use something like the following:

```
IF ( '$(DeployType)' = 'Test')
BEGIN
PRINT 'Running Post-Deploy Scripts for Test'

-- :r .\MyTestScript.sql
END
```